# How can I create a condition to check the class used to create a KClass instance in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, reflection

In the code below I wanna know what was the class used to create a KClass instance. In the array case I found a way using `java.IsArray`, but how to do it for the other cases?

```
fun main() {

    val myKClassList = listOf(String::class, Array<String>::class, Int::class)

    myKClassList.forEach {
            if (it.java.isArray) println("Array")
            else if (??) println("String")
            else if (??) println("Int")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you need is the string representation, you can use the `simpleName` or `qualifiedName` property:

```
for (it in myKClassList) {
    println(it.simpleName)
}
```

If you need the actual class, you already have that--it's the KClass instance. So if you're doing something based on the type:

```
for (it in myKClassList) {
    when (it) {
        Array<String>::class -> println("String array")
        String::class -> println("String")
        Int::class -> println("Int")
        //etc.
    }
}
```

**Edit** If you want to treat all array types the same, we are mixing condition types so you you need `when` without the argument:

```
for (it in myKClassList) {
    when {
        it.java.isArray -> println("Array")
        it == String::class -> println("String")
        it == Int::class -> println("Int")
        //etc.
    }
}
```

Comment: Oops, class literals require the type to be specified.

Comment: It compiles now with Array<String>::class. Is it possible to make it work with any Array independently of they type parameter?

Comment: Array KClasses seem to be some special case in Kotlin (you don't have to specify type for other classes with generics). I don't see a different way than what you were already doing (`.java.isArray`).

Comment: Type parameters are reified in Arrays, probably that's the reason. Otherwise Array<String> wouldn't be recognized in runtime. But I don't know how to adapt the code that I posted to use your solution for other classes.

Comment: Btw you know if it is possible to use a List instead? It doesn't work if I change Array to List when I'm creating the Kclass list.

Comment: I added a version that treats all array types the same.

Comment: And Lists cannot have the type specified because their type is not reified like they are with Arrays (like you said). So you would use `List::class` with no type.

Comment: Thank you very much, it was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the instance type check, consider [`is`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html):

```
when (it) {
    is Int -> println("Int")
    is String -> println("String")
    ...
}
```

Comment: `it` in this case is of type KClass